# Error del Framework en el IIS windows server

Tags: asp, iis, webforms

Previamente publicaba mis proyectos de ASP en IIS y los visualizaba correctamente.

Actualmente, Refresco mi proyecto con actualizaciones realizadas y recibo un error de framework.

Actualmente en el Web config del proyecto dejé: 4.5.2 , aunque previamente tenía el 4.5 , pero aunque tenga el 4.5 no resuelve mi error.

Adjunto Las siguientes imágenes.

[image: ERROR]

[image: Panel de Control]

Adjunto También el código fuente del web config.

```
            <!--
              Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación de ASP.NET, visite
              http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
              -->
            <configuration>
                <configSections>
                    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
                        <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
                        <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
                        <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
                        <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
                    </sectionGroup>
                </configSections>
                <appSettings>
                    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"/>
                </appSettings>
                <connectionStrings>
                    <add name="VFINConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVIDORVISUAL;Initial Catalog=VFIN;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=KolaShaler2012" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
                    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=SERVIDORVISUAL;Initial Catalog=RM_Debug;user id=sa;password=KolaShaler2012;"/>
                <add name="constrVFIN" connectionString="Data Source=SERVIDORVISUAL;Initial Catalog=VFIN;user id=sa;password=KolaShaler2012;"/>
                <add name="constrSHALER" connectionString="Data Source=SERVIDORVISUAL;Initial Catalog=SHALER;user id=sa;password=KolaShaler2012;"/>
                <!--<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=NCALERO-PC;Initial Catalog=LoginDB;user id=sa;password=KolaShaler2012;"/>-->
                </connectionStrings>
                <system.web>
                    <pages>
                        <controls>
                            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                        </controls>
                    </pages>
                    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Ui/BalanceSheet/PaginaError.aspx">
                    </customErrors>
                    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
                        <assemblies>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v15.1.Web, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Charts.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Utils.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraScheduler.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                            <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                            <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/></assemblies>
                    </compilation>
                    <authentication mode="Forms">
                        <forms defaultUrl="~/Inicio.aspx" loginUrl="~/Ui/BalanceSheet/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="25"></forms>
                    </authentication>
                    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
                    <globalization culture="es-NI" uiCulture="es-NI"/>
                    <httpModules>
                        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
                    </httpModules>
                    <httpHandlers>
                        <add path="DX.ashx" verb="GET" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" validate="false"/>
                        <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
                    </httpHandlers>
                </system.web>
                <system.webServer>
                    <modules>
                        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
                    </modules>
                    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
                    <handlers>
                        <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
                        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
                        <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                    </handlers>
                </system.webServer>
                <devExpress>
                    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies=""/>
                    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true"/>
                    <settings doctypeMode="Xhtml" rightToLeft="false" embedRequiredClientLibraries="false" ieCompatibilityVersion="edge"/>
                    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl=""/>
                </devExpress>
            </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has probado parate sobre Grupo de aplicaciones y modificar el Framework de DefaulAppPool?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba seleccionar el framework que necesitas y me comentas.

Comment: Excelente, Muchas gracias.